# Why does the inclusion of an unused bool affect the reference of a char?

Tags: c++, g++

This code...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char c = 'A';
    std::cout << &c;
    return 0;
}
```

...correctly outputs "A" both in Eclipse debug mode and on the command line.

However when I modify the code to...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char c = 'A';
    bool b = true;
    std::cout << &c;
    return 0;
}
```

...it outputs "A␁" (the latin letter 'A' followed by the 'start of header' ASCII control character) in Eclipse debug mode and on the Windows 7 command line. Incidentally, when using `bool b = false` instead I don't get the ␁ character.

I know ␀ has the value 0, and ␁ has the value 1, but why is `cout << &c` affected by the bool? Can anyone explain why this is?

**Edit**: forgot to add my environment: Windows 7 64-bit, MinGW with g++ 4.5.2, in Eclipse Indigo

Comment: I actually get A 4 in gcc sometimes. Other times just A. UB.

Comment: I don't know but this thing works fine for me both ways either false or true

Comment: @Shadow: No it doesn't. It merely _appears_ to sometimes.

Comment: @Tomalak I am still learning C++ pointers so you should forgive any inaccurate wording.  I thought `&c` was a reference.  If it is not, then what should I call it?

Comment: It's a pointer, obtained using the address-of operator `&` (not to be confused with the `&` in a reference type like `char&`). The double meaning of `*` and `&` is highly confusing, so don't feel too bad!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version you are getting (un)lucky.

In the second one you are getting (un)lucky (that it does not crash) but it prints more garbage.

When you use & on a char object you get a char*. When you try and stream a char* it acts differently to all other pointers (which normally prints the address). But a char* is assumed to be a C-String. A C-String is a sequence of bytes terminated by a null character '\0';

What is actually happening is that it is printing every memory location (treating it as a char) starting at the variable 'c' and moving through memory until it finds the character '\0'

#### Example 1 above:

In your case you are lucky there happens to be a null character lying around in memory just after the variable 'c'.

#### Example 2 above:

In your case you are lucky there happens to be a null character lying around in memory just after the variable 'b'. But the variable 'b' is also be interpreted.

- When the value of 'b' is false: converted to a char this is '\0' (same thing). So only the letter 'A' is printed.
- When the value of 'b' is true: converted to a char this is '\01'. Not '\0' so it is printed. You are then lucky that the next byte is a '\0' and the printing stops.

#### What you actually wanted to do was:

```
std::cout << c; // prints a character
```

Or you could have created a string:

```
char const* c = "A";  // Creates a null terminated C-String. Note the double quotes " "
```

Or to get the address

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&c); // All other pointer types will print the address
                                     // Of the standard types only char* is treated 
                                     // differently with its own overload.
```

Comment: I downvoted it initially because it was too terse, but gave upvote back when the answer was improved.

Comment: That said, the answer is far more substantial now so my downvote can go, too. I still think that wording on luck should be changed, though...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!  I was trying to get the address in memory of `c` rather than the value of `c` - but as I didn't state this you were not to know :)

Comment: @Alf: I would be the devil advocate here, I think it is up to anyone to choose how to vote. Voting is necessarily subjective anyway, and do remember than downvotes (unlike upvotes) are repercuted on the voter's score... as long as they comment too, I'm fine with it. Though as noted by Steve, "commenting" might be 1) upvote a technically correct answer, 2) upvote an already existing comment or 3) leave a comment of my own.

Answer (score 8):

`&c` is not passing a reference to `c`, it is passing the address of `c`.  That is, you're passing a `char*` to `operator<<`.  The function will walk memory starting with `&c` and ending when it finds a `\0`.

Because you don't have a null-terminated string, you're invoking undefined behavior as the function walks past the end of `c`'s memory.

Have you tried the following?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char c = 'A';
    std::cout << c << std::endl; // no & needed.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A `char*` is assumed to point to a C style string (zero terminated), not a single character.

If you want to display the address (pointer value) instead, try

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&c);
```

Comment: Shame nobody else mentioned this.

Comment: @Tomalak: Good point, but how would we know he wanted to do that?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: You don't. And you don't know that he didn't, either. So, a great answer would talk about _both_. As it goes, this gets +1 for making a good point that nobody else thought of.

Comment: @Tomalak: Chill. I upvoted it too. I am just making the point that unless you are a psychic, who knows what he wants.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: "Chill"? You don't have to be psychic; an experienced developer can take an educated guess, as evidenced by both this answer and all the other ones.

Comment: @Tomalak: Read your comment to yourself and see why I said "Chill" :) I comes off with a snide tone.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I know what my comment says; I wrote it! There is nothing "unchilled" about me, thanks. I simply choose not to plaster my comments with pointless emoticons.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: What now? How about we just leave it at "don't tell me what to do"? Cheers!

Comment: @CodeMonkey: :( Oh well, maybe one day!

Comment: This is indeed what I was trying to do so thank you for the addition! (It would seem I can't up vote this yet but it definitely would if I could)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: `operator<<` is passed the address of a `char`, and assumes that it is the address of the first `char` in a nullterminated string. It isn't, except by happenchance. The code has UB.